# Youtube URL extractions

Tags: parsing, youtube

I have a program that will take the HTML from a youtube page, extract an encoded MP4 playback URL, deconstruct the key value pairs, and then recombine to create a valid URL

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("url_encoded_fmt_stream_map\":\".*?([^,]|[^\"]+?type=video%2Fmp4.*?)(?=,)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
    m.find();
    String encodedMP4URL = URLDecoder.decode(m.group(1), "UTF-8");
    //get MP4 encoded URL

    HashMap<String, String> pairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] temp = encodedMP4URL.split("&");
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i ++)
        if (!temp[i].contains("url="))
            pairs.put(temp[i].split("=")[0], temp[i].split("=")[1]);
        else {
            String URLPart = temp[i].split("\\?")[0] + "?";
            pairs.put(URLPart.split("=")[0], URLPart.split("=")[1]);
            String otherPart = temp[i].split("\\?")[1];
            pairs.put(otherPart.split("=")[0], otherPart.split("=")[1]);
        }
    //decode String into key value pairs

    pairs.remove("quality");
    pairs.remove("type");
    //remove pairs that aren't used

    StringBuilder realURL = new StringBuilder(pairs.get("url"));
    pairs.remove("url");
    //add url base then remove key/value pair from map

    for (String s : pairs.keySet())
        if (s.equals("s"))
            realURL.append("signature=" + pairs.get(s) + "&");
        else
            realURL.append(s + "=" + pairs.get(s) + "&");
    //encode URL properly with required params
```

This works for what i assume to be all non-copyright videos (ie. any homemade video). However it does not seem to work for videos that i assume have some sort of copyright associated with them. With the videos that it does not work with, the url_encoded_fmt_stream_map does not seem to contain any other data that i could use.

Comment: What's your question? It isn't exactly clear. When it "does not seem to work", what behavior are you observing? How does that behavior differ from the intended behavior?

Comment: My program extracts a valid URL for non copyright videos, but the extracted URL returns a 403 for videos that i assume to be copyrighted